# How to approach this?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

### Recently in my Interview i was asked an algorithmic question:

Given heights of n rows of grass H[n]. A farmer does the following operation k times->
Selects start index (s), end index (e) and a height (h). Fixes his grass trimming instrument at height h and trims the grass from row-s to row-e. Meaning, for each H[i] for i between s and e, H[i]=min(H[i],h).
Print all heights after k operations.

Attention -> If H[i] was 6 and h was 4, then after trimming H[i] becomes 4 (does not reduce by 4)

Use of segment/Fenwick tree was prohibited and the interview wanted something better than O(nk). How to solve this?

The question can also be found at
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/directi-interview-set-12-on-campus/
(Round 4 question)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to remove redundant operations to then just pass through the array once doing min(H[i],h), leaving all the heights set, this will be O(n). Removing the redundant operations requires you to sort them and some fors, so the complexity will be O(n + klog(k) + k) = O(n + klog(k)).

To remove the redundant operations you will first sort them based on the initial position only.

Then:

```
for(int x=0;x<oper.length;x++){
    int curr = x+1;
    while(oper[curr].start<oper[x].end){
        if(oper[curr].height > oper[x].height)
            oper[curr].start = oper[x].end;// When you for through the operations you will go from the start to the end of it, if the start is after the end you will not trim
        else { // oper[curr].height<=oper[x].height
            if(oper[x].end<oper[curr].end){
                oper[x].end = oper[curr].start;
            }
            else {
                /**
                 * Make another operation that starts at the end of oper[curr]
                 * and ends at the end of oper[x], and insert it accordingly
                 * in oper. Then make oper[x] end at oper[curr].start
                 * */
            }
        }
        curr++;
    }
}
// Now no operation overlaps with one another.
// When operations where overlapping only the minimum was saved

// Now trim
for(int x = 0;x<oper.length;x++){
    for(int s = oper[x].start;s<oper[x].end;s++){
        h[s] = min(oper[x].height,h[s]);
    }
}
```

Combine this with Dominique's approach to saving the heights and you have a very fast algorithm.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate a bit more? I tried to understand your solution using pen and paper but its not working for me..

Comment: The approach is check which cuts are useless because a shorter cut will be done later. Is there something specifically that you cannot understand, or the approach as a whole?

Comment: How to achieve the else part?(in less than O(n)) And it will be good if you can explain the intuition of why your algorithm is correct?

Comment: Complexity doesnt seems to be O(klogk),because for cases where k = 3,and the i2 intervals given are - start1 = 2,end1 = 5,h1 = 4 and start2= 4,end2 = 4 and h2 = 3,your algo fails to remove redundant ranges